# How to enable bash completion on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine

The compute instances I'm running is a Debian Buster. Normally there's exists a `/etc/bash_completion` file. However for GCE, it's missing. There's even a section they've added in the default `~/.bashrc` to refer to the bash completion files which none of them exists.

```sh
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Did you install bash-completion?

Comment: *facepalm*, there we go. Now I'm embarrassed. I expected if it's mentioned in ~/.bashrc then GCE would've installed it by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, it is not installed by default, I tried it in my own project creating a new Debian Buster VM instance, and `/etc/bash_completion` doesn't exist.

```sh
/etc$ ls -l bash_completion
ls: cannot access 'bash_completion': No such file or directory
```

Only after installing bash-completion, the  `/etc/bash_completion` file will appears.

```sh
sudo apt-get install bash-completion
```

```sh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bash-completion
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 208 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1397 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 bash-completion all 1:2.8-6 [208 kB]
Fetched 208 kB in 0s (960 kB/s)     
Selecting previously unselected package bash-completion.
(Reading database ... 37801 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bash-completion_1%3a2.8-6_all.deb ...
Unpacking bash-completion (1:2.8-6) ...
Setting up bash-completion (1:2.8-6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
```

After the installation:

```sh
/etc$ ls -l bash_completion
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 45 Feb 11  2019 bash_completion
```